# How to clear Canvas in Opera?

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone please help me?
I have the following code and it seems to work fine in Chrome, but does not work in Opera.
Here is the code:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
```

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = canvas.width;

Using above code to clear the line after drawing, it works fine in Chrome, but in Opera it the drawing did not get cleared.  Please help.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Why not use `clearRect`? It was born to do this.

Comment: Yes, I did use clearRect, but does not well.

Comment: It should, you just have to make sure there aren't any transforms and that you're encompassing the whole canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Use clearRect(); This is th only method I know which clears the canvas

clear the expected area you want or provide height and width of entire canvas. If you provide the dimensions of entire canvas you will have to redraw it completely.